# Is there a way to save a file in vim in Windows without marking it executable?

Tags: windows, vim

Heading says it all really.  Using Windows 7 and latest stable gvim, whenever I save (`:w`) a file it's marked executable.  I'm doing cross-platform development and it'd be nice if this didn't happen.

Comment: I am not sure how a file on Windows is marked executable?

Comment: Neither am I, but a file that's not executable in the repository before I edit it, is executable afterward.

Comment: What is the name of the file you are saving.  Or, more importantly, the extension?

Comment: What repository? Windows 7 does not come with a repository, unless you consider the file system to be a repository. Also, a file on Windows 7 is considered executable based on it's file extension, not based on file attributes or content. Thus, unless gvim actually changes the name of the file, it's not possible for the file to be executable.

Comment: It's a file in a mercurial repository (stored on linux).  All the files are .py.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with vim and everything to do with filesystems.  Try opening a file from the repo in another editor (in Windows) and saving it.  Does the same thing happen?

Comment: I'd have to agree with @Randy Morris. This is not a gvim's fault. I would look into how Mercurial deals with the file attributes on the local Linux repo.

Comment: Nope, opening a file in Notepad and editing/saving doesn't change whether it's executable.

Comment: I can also see in cygwin that it's executable before it's committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sceptics: The flag of the files are indeed set as executable. Do a `ls -al` before and after re-saving the file to observe the issue. (install cygwin, or may be other *nix emulations)

@OP: the question have been raised several times in the past. I don't remember the conclusion on the subject. You should search vim mailing-lists archives (vim_use and vim_dev).
May be you can try to add an hook to your RCS (if it supports that) to proceed to a `chmod -x` on file extensions that does not correspond to an executable (*.h, *.cpp, *.vim, ...), or on files that do not contain a shebang (unlike perl, I don't know if python source files may contain a shebang)